# Apache + Chrome + PHP => Infinite Loading

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome

I'm running on a custom local domain a login form. I have a simple router which redirects to the Controller, and the login method of the controller is the following:

```php
public static function login()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        echo "What the f***!";
    } else {
        self::renderLoginForm();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the router:

```php
$requested_path = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2)[0];
try {
    if (preg_match('/[^.]+.css/', $requested_path)) {
        $file_path = __DIR__ . "/Public" . $requested_path;
        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
            header('Content-Type: text/css');
            echo file_get_contents($file_path);
        }
    } elseif (preg_match('/[^.]+.js/', $requested_path)) {
        $file_path = __DIR__ . "/Public" . $requested_path;
        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
            header('Content-Type: text/js');
            echo file_get_contents($file_path);
        }
    } elseif ($requested_path === "/") {
        PageController::homeAction();
    } elseif ($requested_path == "/api/recognize") {
        SoundController::recognizeAction();
    } elseif ($requested_path == "/login") {
        UserController::login();
    } else {
        PageController::notFoundAction();
    }
} catch (Throwable $throwable) {
    if (ISDEV) {
        echo $throwable->getMessage();
        echo $throwable->getTraceAsString();
    } else {
        echo "Erreur 500";
    }
}
```

Using GET method, the form is well rendered, I can refresh, do anything, everything works. But when I'm validating my form, Chrome starts in an infinite loading (Not displaying my echo).
I tried the following:

- Safari or Postman => POST works like a charm
- Chrome + XDebug => POST works like a charm
- Clear all data, then Chrome => POST does not work
- Private Navigation Window => POST does not work
- Restart server then Chrome => POST does not work
- Restart MBPro then Chrome => POST does not work

*I double checked that it's same URL, and same ports everytime.*

*I had this problem prior to XDebug installation. Actually this problem is the reason why I installed XDebug*

If you have any idea where it could come from, that would be very very helpful, because I'm running out of things to try.

*EDIT with CAUSE*

I finally found why, even if I don't know how to solve it. When I don't set any password, the POST is sent well, without any problem, the problem occurs only when I set a password.
After uninstalling and installing Chrome, it finally worked with password set, but taking a lot of time loading, before showing me the Save password popup.
After finding this cause, I switch off my internet connection, and then it worked like a charm.

*Then question*

Does anyone know how to disable the automatic save password popup for some domains only?

Comment: Can you show us the router?

Comment: What does your Chrome Inspector say?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Done, Martin Nothing, the network part remains empty

Comment: what about the console log in Inspector?

Comment: @Martin, nothing in it, clean

Comment: Use `application/javascript` as content-type for js files

Comment: Also if you are on a linux machine then check the error logs at `var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: And Network part should not be empty it should have at least one entry check that you haven't enabled any filter on that?